# React - how to use hooks to hide or show a component based on an onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to use react hooks to hide or show a component based on an onChange event (a selected option being selected in a form).

I have a component called Animal, which will be hidden until someone selects 'animals' from a select menu in a form.

This is what I have tried to make:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useForm from "react-hook-form";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import Animal from "./tips/Animal";


const specialFeatures = [
  { value: "animals", label: "Animals" },
  { value: "none", label: "None of these apply" }
];

const Method = props => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, errors, reset } = useForm();

  const [valuesSpecialFeatures, setSpecialFeatures] = useState([]);
  const [showAnimal, setShowAnimal] = useState(false);


  const handleMultiChangeSpecialFeatures = selectedOption => {
    setValue("specialFeatures", selectedOption, true);
    setSpecialFeatures(selectedOption);
    if selectedOption === 'animals' setAnimal(!<Animal />)
  };


  return (
    <div>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

          <label>Does this proposal incldue any of these features?</label>
          <Select
            className="reactSelect"
            name="specialFeatures"
            placeholder="Select at least one"
            value={valuesSpecialFeatures}
            options={specialFeatures}
            onChange={handleMultiChangeSpecialFeatures}
            isMulti
          />

          { showAnimal && "animals" <Animal /> }

          <input type="submit" value="next" />
        </form>

    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Method);
```

I'm trying to test if the form field named specialFeatures has a selectedOption that includes the value 'animals', then if it does, I want to display the Animal component beneath that field.

This attempt is clearly incorrect, but I can't see how to set the useEffect to toggle visibility.

Comment: What is this part about? `setAnimal(!<Animal />)`. There is no `setAnimal` in your code, and can't you just set to `false`? `!<Animal />` is a forced conversion to boolean. Will always asserts to `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to set `showAnimal` state to a boolean and then use that to either show or hide the component:

```
const Method = props => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, errors, reset } = useForm();
  const [valuesSpecialFeatures, setSpecialFeatures] = useState([]);
  const [showAnimal, setShowAnimal] = useState(false);

  const handleMultiChangeSpecialFeatures = selectedOption => {
    setValue("specialFeatures", selectedOption, true);
    setSpecialFeatures(selectedOption);
    setShowAnimal(selectedOption.some(option => option.value === "animals")); // Toggle 'showAnimal'
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>Does this proposal incldue any of these features?</label>
        <Select
          className="reactSelect"
          name="specialFeatures"
          placeholder="Select at least one"
          value={valuesSpecialFeatures}
          options={specialFeatures}
          onChange={handleMultiChangeSpecialFeatures}
          isMulti
        />
        {showAnimal && <Animal />} // Render component based on the toggle
        <input type="submit" value="next" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

There's a simpler alternative though, which doesn't involve setting the value to the state, you can just derive it during render instead:

```
const Method = props => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, errors, reset } = useForm();

  const [valuesSpecialFeatures, setSpecialFeatures] = useState([]);

  const handleMultiChangeSpecialFeatures = selectedOption => {
    setValue("specialFeatures", selectedOption, true);
    setSpecialFeatures(selectedOption);
  };

  // Derive the value based on the value of `valuesSpecialFeatures`
  const isAnimalSelected = valuesSpecialFeatures.some(
    option => option.value === "animals"
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>Does this proposal incldue any of these features?</label>
        <Select
          className="reactSelect"
          name="specialFeatures"
          placeholder="Select at least one"
          value={valuesSpecialFeatures}
          options={specialFeatures}
          onChange={handleMultiChangeSpecialFeatures}
          isMulti
        />
        {isAnimalSelected && <Animal />} // Use derived value to render component
        <input type="submit" value="next" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It seems that `<Select/>` allows multiple options to be selected which means that `selectedOption` is probably an array (multiple options) not a string.

Comment: Ah, missed that it was `react-select`. Now see it has `isMulti` set also...